# calling MainActivty's method from another java class without onCreate

Tags: android

I have one java class. AlarmReceiver.java
I have AddReminderActivity and inside that I have one public method which I'm calling from AlarmReceiver.java directly. Remember (AddReminderActivity onCreate will not be called in this case.
In that particular method, I'm using getApplicationContext, which I'm getting NullPointer
........
Can I use any method without calling AddReminderActivity?
Method inside AddReminderActivity: 
code:

```
public void notifyInAdv(int reminderId, Intent intent) {
        if (notificationDay < 1 || intent != null) {
            if (intent != null) {
                mCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, mDay);
            } else {
                mCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, mDay - notificationDay);
            }
            mCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, mMonth);
            mCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, mYear);
            mCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, mHour);
            mCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mMinute);
            mCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            new AlarmReceiver().createExactAlarm(getApplicationContext(), mCalendar, reminderId);
```

**AlarmReceiver.java:**

```
 new AddReminderActivity().notifyInAdv(mReceivedID, intent);
```

Comment: How are you getting the instance of MainActivity in ABC.java?

Comment: @MohammedAtif new AddReminderActivity().notifyInAdv(mReceivedID, intent);

Comment: So this `new MainActivity()` creates new object of MainActivity. It is obviously not the one which has been loaded by the OS. Either use dependency injection or figure out a way to pass the instance of MainActivity to ABC.java.

Comment: @MohammedAtif How can I do that?

Comment: One more question, why did you even write this method in mainActivity? it shouldn’t be here technically.

Comment: Where are you creating the instance of ABC.java?

Comment: see the edited question.

Comment: @MohammedAtif once first reminder complete and it come in AlarmReceiver's onReceive, from that I'm calling AddReminderActivity's method to notifyInAdv again for some different time, and that method will call again AlarmReceiver's class and set the reminder.

Comment: @MohammedAtif reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sending a notification you need `application context`. The way you have followed is wrong because creating instance for your activity should be done by OS. Then only you will application context instance with `getApplicationContext` method.

I didn't understand this clearly.
*Can I use any method without calling AddReminderActivity?*

As per your comments I understood that you want to send notification from the `AlarmReciever`.

Answer to your question as per my understanding:

Make `notifyInAdv` method as static and pass context as parameter.

Trigger same method from `AlarmReciever` call as `notifyInAdv(recieverContext, .....your other params......)` .

```
public static void notifyInAdv(Context context, int reminderId, Intent intent) {
    if (notificationDay < 1 || intent != null) {
        if (intent != null) {
            mCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, mDay);
        } else {
            mCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, mDay - notificationDay);
        }
        mCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, mMonth);
        mCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, mYear);
        mCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, mHour);
        mCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mMinute);
        mCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        new AlarmReceiver().createExactAlarm(context, mCalendar, reminderId);
    }
}
```

Use the method in your receiver like below

`AddReminderActivity.notifyInAdv(alarmReceiverContext, mReceivedID, intent);`

This should work.

But this is *not best practice*.

Create some `Utility` class and place such static methods(like sending notification, common string to date and date to string parsings, etc..) ,  to send notification and that method from other places where ever you need in your application.

Comment: Can you help me for one thing?

Comment: Yes jimmy. Tell me

Comment: use static method and pass context object from the activity where you are going to call that method.. that it...